# GitHub Pull and Push changes not working

Tags: git, github

I have a Windows 8 laptop. I have a gitHub installed. Till yesterday i was able to push and pull my changes using the github client. It was working fine. 
Since today morning I am not able to pull or push any changes. It is giving me following error.

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/SomeName/app-perks.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443**

We dont have any proxy settings for our network.

What I tried: 
I reinstalled the github for windows and tried. But it gave same.
I removed the rtepository and tried. Even it is giving the same.
It was working fine till yesterday.

Kindly help.!
Thank you.

Comment: What is your git version? try using Git bash and see whether it could connect.

Comment: 2.8.1.1 , downloaded today. It is showing GitHub for Windows is up to date

Comment: ya I have downloaded and installed gitBash 1.9.5 preview.. But dont know how to use it.

Comment: Just open git bash, go to your repo folder and issue `git pull` command

Comment: It is giving the same for gitBash too...

Comment: Then it might be a ssh problem.